# Facebook STS without ACS

Tags: facebook, wif, claims-based-identity

Is it possible to use facebook authentification with WIF without using an acs/azure?  Or this is absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible but you'll have to write a bit of code. There is a WIF extension that adds OAuth 2.0 support to the framework:

https://connect.microsoft.com/site1168/Downloads

Another option you might consider:

http://facebooknet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Just to note that this is a CTP release - fine to play around with - but you can't deploy to Production.

Answer (score 0):

The [Facebook Platform uses OAuth 2.0](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) for authentication and authorization. So when you try to build an authentication application for Facebook you are actually looking for a provided which supports Claim Based authentication. WIF does provide ASP.NET and WCF based framework for you to authenticate your application with Facebook through a claim based Identity Framework. ([Windows Azure ACS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185937.aspx) simplify this process to bare minimum level and that is what you pay for.)

Comment: That's just a Facebook "Like" page - it's doesn't actually say Facebook uses it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your own STS and add [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) to it.

[IdentityServer](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/) does something like this with OpenId in a (hidden) page. This was based on a post from Matias Woloski, updated [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/mwoloski/2010/07/12/consumer-identities-for-business-transactions/).